# Change sendSynchronousRequest to sendASynchronousRequest in ios6? Crashing iPhone5 in 3G connections

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, ios6, xcode4.5

I've been tweaking the code to have my app working on the new iOS6/iPhone5.

Everything seemed to be working fine until a user told me that the app is hangs in the welcome screen in his iPhone5 when connecting thru 3G, all goes well using wifi.

He sent me the crashlog and I've noticed that the problem is linked to the "sendSynchronousRequest" part I have in the following code:

```
- (void)loadCurrentURL {   NSString *appURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", app_SERVER_URL, @"auth/app/register"];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
NSError *error;

[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]] returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    self.currentValidURL = app_SERVER_URL;
} else {
    self.currentValidURL = app_APPLE_TEST_URL;
}
}
```

So after much research in Apple's Docs and here in StackOverFlow, I've changed the code to this:

```
- (void)loadCurrentURL{   NSString *appURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", app_SERVER_URL, @"auth/app/register"];

 NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];

 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]]
 queue:queue
 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
 NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
 if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
 self.currentValidURL = app_SERVER_URL;
 } else {
 self.currentValidURL = app_APPLE_TEST_URL;
 }
 }];
}
```

Problem now is that it hangs in my iPhone4 device and iOS5,6 simulators.

I'm not an expert developer, I'm learning so I would like to know if anyone has an answer for this.Any help will be MUCH appreciated :)

Thank you so much in advance.

(I'm aware that there are other similar questions on stackOverFlow but none seems to get this solved.)

Comment: The first thing to do is wrap the code in your completion block with an if (error == nil)... else NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription) to see if you're getting an error. I would also use requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval: to create your request so you can set a time out interval.

Comment: Thanks, @rdelmar. It's a good idea for sure. Will try.

Comment: didi it work? how did you solve this issue? even I am hung at the same situation but with 2G connection. :(

Comment: Hi @Nikita, around that time and since we had several other issues concerning connection, we decided to refactor the code and applied different kind of methods to do so. So, I'm sorry to tell that I don't know if it works.